# Unexpected tuple iteration in Julia?

Tags: tuples, iteration, julia

I wanted to iterate over triplets in a tuple and found a weird comma detail in Julia is that what we should expect?

```
julia> for (k, n, d) in (("x1", "x2", "x3"),); @show k, n, d; end;
(k, n, d) = ("x1", "x2", "x3")    
# However if I remove , it doesn't work
julia> for (k, n, d) in (("x1", "x2", "x3")); @show k, n, d; end;
ERROR: BoundsError
Stacktrace:
[1] indexed_next(::String, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./tuple.jl:56
[2] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is behaving as expected.  Parentheses alone do not create tuples. If they did, simply basic math expressions like `2*(3+4)` wouldn't work.  Parentheses without commas or semicolons in them are used for precedence groupings or function calls.  That's why you need that explicit trailing comma in the one-tuple case.

`((x,y,z))` is the same as `(x,y,z)`.
`((x,y,z),)` constructs a one-tuple that contains `(x,y,z)`.